# C++ communicate across processes

Tags: c++, process, communication

I have a dll that is loaded into multiple processes. 
What would be a clean way to have communication across those processes/dlls.
Sending simple strings is the goal. 
I would prefer to avoid sendmessage, file io, and sending the address of the string command.

Comment: Windows registry? you may find more proposals here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008957/interprocess-communication-on-windows

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would look into [shared memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory).  There's a nice [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366551(VS.85).aspx) on MSDN.

Keep in mind that just like when using threads in the same process, access to shared memory is not serialized.  You'll need some form of synchronization (e.g. a named mutex) to serialize access to the memory block.

Comment: See also how DLL can create shared memory as part of the DLL itself.   http://www.codeproject.com/KB/DLL/Share_memory_throuth_DLL.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're coding for Windows.

Named pipes are probably the best solution if your communications are point-to-point between processes.  You can easily design client/server-style protocols such as this:

*Client: Here is data to process*

*Server: Here are the results of processing your request*

Named pipes will also port easily to other point-to-point mechanisms such as sockets or anonymous pipes.

If your communications aren't point-to-point and you need to maintain common shared data among multiple processes, then memory mapped files as suggested by Andre' are a better choice, but will definitely need mutex protection to be reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Since everyone else assumed Windows can I assume UcOs/II? Use a Message Mailbox. OK I figure if you are on windows there has to be something similar a quick google turned up [Mailslots](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365576%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has a pretty comprehensive overview over the different methods for inter-process communication.

[The article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/interprocess-communications) explains the pros and cons of the most common methods. Among them are

- Data Copy (Message Passing)
- File Mapping (Named Shared Memory)
- Pipes
- Remote Procedure Call
  and more.

Each section of the article gives links to further documentation including some **very useful code-examples**.